# What is the relationship between the Node version and Electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an Electron 7.2.4 project, which bundles Node `12.8.1`. In this app's top-most package.json, it specifies a node engine range of `>= 10.15 < 12.0.0`. On my development machine, I have Node `10.15.0` installed. That's three versions/ranges of Node I am trying to grapple with to understand their meaning in the context of the project.

How do these versions relate? Should they all be the same?

Answer (score 0):

It means that any version from 10.15.0 to 12.0.0 is supported and tested to work by the devs. Often a later version will work but is not tested or supported but may also cause known issues.

Comment: How does that relate to the bundled version of Electron? In this example, Electron is bundling Node 12.8.1, but package.json says it only supports Node >= 10.15 < 12.0.0. Is the value in package.json irrelevant in this case?

Comment: If it works then don't panic. If you are worried then install a supported version. They wouldn't bundle it if there were known issues.